# How to define a function(expression dependant on other columns) as a default value to a column while defining table in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How to add a function/expression which takes arguments as other columns as a default value to a column in the table of SQLAlchemy? For example: I want to define c as a column which is 2*x(other column);which should be saved in the database(could be in other table too).  Can @hybrid_property decorator be used in this context?

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, aliased
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property, hybrid_method
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///Helloworld.db', echo=False)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
metadata = MetaData(engine)
Base = declarative_base()

class HelloWorld(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'helloworld'
    pm_key = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    x = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    c = Column(Integer,default=2*x)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. Below I'am just adding a piece of code you can try . For more I think [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#context-sensitive-default-functions) will help you.

```
def mydefault(context):
    return context.current_parameters.get('X')

class HelloWorld(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'helloworld'
    pm_key = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    x = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    c = Column(Integer,default=mydefault)
```

Comment: How this new column(c) can be converted to mutable?

Comment: @Apurva for making mutable columns there is one option like `Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(PickleType))` in sqlalchemy.  I'am mentioning a reference [link here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/mutable.html) Because I don't know what exactly you are looking for. You can go through it and you can share with us your doubts :)

Comment: So , all I need here is a column which is dependent on other column and it should be mutable i.e., if I change the expression to 3*x in the future; all the changes should be emitted and all the previously saved data should get affected with this.