# Update SQLAlchemy column of my referral when my own column changes

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Any time my wallet_1 is been modified with +1 or any value, I want to get the value and add it into the wallet_2 of my referral wallet which is (Joshua wallet_2) as well as for wallet_2, if my wallet_2 is been modified with +1 or any value, I want to get the value and add it into the wallet_3 of my referral wallet which is (Joshua wallet_3).

```
def User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String)
    my_referral = db.Column(db.String) #referral = Joshua

def Wallet(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    wallet_1 = db.Column(db.Float, default=0.0)
    wallet_2 = db.Column(db.Float, default=0.0)
    wallet_3 = db.Column(db.Float, default=0.0)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401951/how-to-define-a-functionexpression-dependant-on-other-columns-as-a-default-val

Comment: please @Shenix can you sheld more light on it to me please i really dont understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why aren't you using classes to build db models?

Based on what I managed to find [on sqlalchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/defaults.html#context-sensitive-default-functions), try this approach.

`If you want to even update wallet3 based on what's happening in wallet2` - you can always set a few functions like update_wallet. Eg. update_wallet2 etc... which are gonna be referring to each other. I don't have access to your application and whole environment, and from my point of view this is the most I can do to help. Stop speculating, overthinking it and just go and try setting up those functions, then test & debug till you success.

```
def update_wallet(context):
    return context.get_current_parameters()['wallet_1']

# every function gonna follow the same pattern
def update_wallet3(context):
    return context.get_current_parameters()['wallet_2']


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String)
    referral = db.Column(db.String)
    

class Wallet(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    wallet_1 = db.Column(db.Float, default=0.0)
    wallet_2 = db.Column(db.Float, default=0.0, onupdate=update_wallet)
    wallet_3 = db.Column(db.Float, default=0.0, onupdate=update_wallet3)
```

So, the **update_wallet** function is being triggered when INSERT or UPDATE statement occurrs on the wallet_1 column. It is retrieving the given value, and inserting/updating it for the wallet_2.

Just like I mentioned before, carefully try to read through the sqlalchemy docs. Good luck.

Comment: ok are you saying that e.g wallet_1 was == 2 in it former state, and when ever a update of  +1 occure to it making it ==3 it will also add +1 to the wallet_2 or it will just get all total of wallet_1 and add it into wallet_2, and secondly how can i write more fucntion into the wallet_1 and as well wallet_2 that will work this way: When ever INSERT or UPDATE statement occurs on wallet_1 it will get the referral id in the User Model and add that given value to the wallet_2 of that referral id, because the referral belong to someone else in the system, so i want to add the given value to is...

Comment: own wallet _2 as well, and also applicable to wallet_2, when ever INSERT or UPDATE occurs on wallet_2 i want to get the value and add it to the wallet_3 of the referral id in the User Model, it will search if the referral id exist it will add that given value to the wallet but if the referral id is not exisiting it will just pass, and also it will check if there is a referral id in the User Model, if there is not it will as well Pass. Thanks, i will be very grateful if you can help me please.

Comment: It's really difficult to understand what are you trying to achieve based on your comments. If you could modify your original post with additional consternations and questions - that would be very helpful and easier. After that, I will do my best to help you and I will also modify my answer on this thread.

Comment: am going to modify the question. Thansk

Comment: Have remodify the way i asked the question for a better understanding of what am trying to achieve. Thanks  @vicaris

Comment: Check modified version.

Comment: i really appreciate you @vicaris for trying to help me on this, but still some little error you are not getting, 1. am not trying to update the user wallet_2 and wallet_3 with the values does functions retrieve, am trying to add that value to the wallet_2 and wallet_3 of that users referral wallet table not is personal wallet but for that of is referral. Thanks

Comment: for example i want to be able to write a function like: 'if wallet_1 == update:' get the user referral, and add 2 to his/her wallet_2. instead of returning the value, i want to write a function that will fetch the user referral, let say for example the user register with a referral code of '22hjio', when any update is been noticed on the user wallet_1 i want to get the user referral which is '22hjio' and add 2 to his wallet_2.